# altering javascript function to fit an AJAX to PHP call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm creating modals to provide information about various countries.
One of the modals I am trying to create is to show the weather and I found this codepen example which is very nice! https://codepen.io/irwingb1979/pen/XWMbqmP

Is there any way to make such a call using javaScript AJAX to a PHP file like such

```
<?php

    // remove for production

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lon=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&units=metric&appid=01a69c43fa692a1e67ae4c9bdabb8fdc';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo var_dump($result, $url);
    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

I'm not quite sure how to alter it to fit my modal and call like above

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean or what the issue is. If you're creating a HTML modal, why not just make the fetch/AJAX call directly to the weather API just like in the codepen example? is there a specific reason you want to send the weather API request from PHP?

Comment: @ADyson They might not allow access from browsers, and that would require exposing the key to the client.

Comment: @Barmar it's clear from the codepen that it does work from browsers. But yes it does mean the App ID is exposed in the JS code.

Comment: @ADyson I'm working on a project for a course, and one of the requirements is that API requests should be made from PHP. This weather example is exactly what I'm looking to achieve, just not done how I need it :(

Comment: Ok. Well all you need to really do in the JS is send a fetch() request to your PHP code, which will then make a request to the weather API. The PHP script echoes the response, which will be received by your JS, and then you can process/display the results. So it's a bit like the PHP code being a form of proxy server, that's all.

Comment: This still has the same problems as in your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237490/ajax-returning-json-string-error-from-php-api-call) - multiple `echo()`s that will break the parsing of the JSON from the last `echo()`